# Modal Alert Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #divdrag1{float:left; width:154px; height:200px; margin:20px;padding:2px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
    #div2,#div3{float:left; width:200px; height:195px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script language="javascript" src="../JS/jQuery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    function allowDrop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    function drag(ev)
    {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }
    var n;

    function drop(ev)
    {
        var len=$("#div2 img").length;
        alert(len);
        if(len > 0)
        {

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                    .html("This is the <i>content</i> of the dialog box.")
                    .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        title: "Title of the dialog box",
                        // add any additional jQuery Dialog options
                        modal: true
                    });
                $("body").delegate("#div2", "click", function() {
                    $dialog.dialog('open');
                    return false;    
                });
            });
        }
        else
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true)); 
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

my html code

```
<body>
    <form id="f1" name="form1" method="post">
        <div id="divdrag1" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" >
            <ul type="none">
                <li><img src="smiley.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31" align="left"> </li>
                <li><img src="pic1.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="88" height="31"> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Clear" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this i don't know what function i have to use in the place of "bind". if i use in button on click its working . but the above code is not working when i change to bind . tell me what to write for div tag .. Please help me friends ...

Comment: When do you want to open the dialog? on click? mouseover?

Comment: Please be explicit when describing the problem and goal. What do you expect the code to do and what wrong thing is it doing now?

Comment: you mean like `$("#div2").bind('click', function() { ... });`

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? did you add also jQuery UI? Check this http://jsfiddle.net/xPA7c/

Comment: when i drop the image in the div tag i have to check the length if that length is greater than 0 then it should display modal alert box

Answer (score 2):

jQUery's [**.bind()**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (*since version 1.7 supressed by [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)*) has this syntax:

```
.bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler(eventObject) )
```

So you need to choose a event type: `click`, `mouseenter`, etc... Which means you probably want this:

```
$("#div2").bind('click',function() {
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xPA7c/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#div2").bind('click',function() {
     $dialog.dialog('open');
     return false;
});
```

Or you should create `dialog` on `click event` of `div` and use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like,

```
 $("#div2").on('click',function() {
      var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                     .html("This is the <i>content</i> of the dialog box.")
                     .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        title: "Title of the dialog box",
                        // add any additional jQuery Dialog options
                         modal: true
                    });

      $dialog.dialog('open');
      return false;
 });
```

Comment: i didn't get the answer Rohan . when i drop the image in div the modal alter must pop up ....

Comment: You can use `mouseenter` event for this in place of `click event`, otherwise you should use a `drag and drop library or plugin`

Comment: i need to pop up the modal box when i drop more than 1 image

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you don't want to use inline onclick but instead let the jquery capture that event.

you can use `.bind()` or `.on()`

```
$("#div2").bind('click',function() {
     $dialog.dialog('open'); // or simply use the selector $('div.dialog') for div that has dialog class
     return false;
});
```

or

```
$("#div2").on('click',function() {
     $dialog.dialog('open');  // or simply use the selector $('div.dialog') for div that has dialog class
     return false;
});
```

same as for your drop and dragover events

```
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                    .html("This is the <i>content</i> of the dialog box.")
                    .dialog({
                             autoOpen: false,
                             title: "Title of the dialog box",
                             // add any additional jQuery Dialog options
                             modal: true
                            });
                        });
```

For older version of jquery

```
$("#div2").live('click', function(){
                 $dialog.dialog('open');
                 return false;
            });
```

For new version of jquery

```
$("body").delegate("#div2", "click", function() {
      $dialog.dialog('open');
       return false;    
});
```

Comment: live() doesn't support

Comment: Yes, it was supported in older version